# Routed feature module vs Routing feature module?

Tags: php, laravel

Hope evrything is fine.

I have laravel project.

Here is the api.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('cors:api')->get('/stores', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\ApiData')->{'GetStores'}();
});

Route::middleware('cors:api')->post('/RegisterLocation', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\ApiData')->{'RegisterLocation'}();
});

Route::middleware('cors:api')->post('/SearchPartner', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\ApiData')->{'SearchPartner'}();
});
```

and here is the web.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/stores', function() {
    return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')->{'show'}();
});
```

However evryrequest that I put in the url, it always redricet to index.php ?

Comment: so if you go to "yourwebsite.idk/stores" id goes to "yourwebsite.idk/"? maybe a .htaccess redirection?

Comment: @Berto99 It gies t the index page. I do not have htaccess file.

Comment: what's your enviroment?

Comment: @Berto99 what you mean ?

Comment: @Berto99 Any chance

Comment: @Berto99 When I run php artisan env I get  Current application environment: local

Comment: @Berto99 Any chance ?

Comment: I mean apache, xampp or what